# Is there a way to add more information when hovering over a Plotly graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I made a graph, which you can see below. When hovering over a Plotly graph, you can see helpful info present in the graph like the `Store Num` etc. Is there a way to add to this label, so when someone hovers they can also see the `branding` ? As in, not just `Store Num`? Thanks!

| Store Num | mean_sales | mean_outreach | branding |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 | 1200 | 1 |
| 2 | 4200 | 1403 | 2 |

```
plotly::ggplotly(ggplot(data, aes(x= mean_sales, y= mean_outreach, label= `Store Num`))+
                   geom_point() +geom_text(aes(label= `Store Num`),hjust=20, vjust=20) +
                   ggtitle("Examining Marketing Campaign Outreach"))
```

When I try writing two labels, then the label itself will change but the value for both `Store Num` and `branding` will be the store number. As in both labels I want aren't showing correctly.

```
plotly::ggplotly(ggplot(data, aes(x= mean_sales, y= mean_outreach, label= `Store Num`))+
                   geom_point() +geom_text(aes(label= branding),hjust=20, vjust=20) +
                   ggtitle("Examining Marketing Campaign Outreach"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve your desired result with a customized tooltip via the `text` aesthetic (see https://plotly-r.com/controlling-tooltips.html#tooltip-text-ggplotly):

```
library(plotly)

ggplot(data, aes(
  x = mean_sales, y = mean_outreach, label = Store.Num,
  text = paste0(
    "mean_sales: ", mean_sales, "<br>",
    "mean_outreach: ", mean_outreach, "<br>",
    "Store Num: ", Store.Num, "<br>",
    "branding: ", branding
  )
)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(hjust = 0, vjust = 0) +
  ggtitle("Examining Marketing Campaign Outreach")

ggplotly(tooltip = "text")
```

Or if you only want to add information to the defaults you could do:

```
ggplot(data, aes(
  x = mean_sales, y = mean_outreach, label = Store.Num,
  text = paste0(
    "branding: ", branding
  )
)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(hjust = 0, vjust = 0) +
  ggtitle("Examining Marketing Campaign Outreach")

ggplotly(tooltip = "all")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know they were called tooltips.